# Counting files and incrementing variable Python

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax, directory

Trying to go through every folder on a drive, count the number of files in each folder and if the number of files is greater than or equal to 3, increment a count. Should be easy right? Well I've completely borked it and I'm at a loss.

```
import os, os.path, sys

rootdir = 'q:'

documentedcount = 0

for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    filecount = len([name for name in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(name)])
    print "Filecount = %s" % filecount
    if  filecount >= 3:
        documentedcount =+1
        print "Documented in the loop is %s" % documentedcount

print "Documented = %s" % documentedcount
```

It doesn't want to go beyond the root directory and into any of the subfolders. It's driving me nuts because this should be simple as hell but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Please correct the indentation to match your actual implementation -- it's significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `os.walk()` won't change the working directory on each iteration, so the line...

```
filecount = len([name for name in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(name)])
```

...will always count the number of files in the current working directory when you started the script.

However, there's a much simpler method, since the third item in each tuple returned by `os.walk()` already gives you a list of all (non-directory) files in the directory, so you can just use `len(files)`...

```
import os, os.path, sys

rootdir = 'q:'

documentedcount = 0

for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    filecount = len(files)
    print "Filecount = %s" % filecount
    if filecount >= 3:
        documentedcount =+1
        print "Documented in the loop is %s" % documentedcount

print "Documented = %s" % documentedcount
```